# How do I edit the default directory listings in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

How do I edit the layout of the default directory listings page (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the way the Default Servlet displays directory listings - check out [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/default-servlet.html#dir). It seems like all you need to do is create the appropriate XSLs.